# Python WindowsError 5 Access Denied

Tags: python, directory, access-denied, windowserror

I created this script that will give me a html file of all files of a given directory and I managed to get it just right, except for one thing: only on Windows, I get this `WindowsError 5 Access Denied` when I try to reach through the C:/ directory.

Here is the source code for my application:

```
import os 
import hashlib
import platform
import sys
import argparse
import HTML

class Map(object):
    
    def __init__(self,param):
        self.param_list = param
        self.slash = self.slash_by_os()
        self.result_list = []
        self.os = ""
        
            
    
    def calc_md5(self,file_path):
        hash = hashlib.md5()
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_to_check:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: file_to_check.read(4096), ''):    
                hash.update(chunk)

        return hash.hexdigest()
        

    def slash_by_os(self):
        general_id = platform.system()
        actual_os = ""

        if general_id == "Darwin" or general_id == "darwin":
            actual_os = "UNIX"
        elif general_id == "Linux" or general_id == "linux":
            actual_os = "UNIX"
        elif general_id  == "SunOS":
            actual_os = "UNIX"
        elif general_id == "Windows" or general_id == "windows":
            actual_os = "WIN"
        else:
            actual_os = general_id
    
        if actual_os == "UNIX":
            return '/'
        elif actual_os == "WIN":
            return '\\'
        else:
            return '/'
        
        self.os = actual_os
    
    def what_to_do(self,new_dir):
        act = []
        act.append(new_dir[:-1])
        for param in self.param_list:
            if param == "md5":
                x = self.calc_md5(new_dir[:-1])
                act.append(x)
            elif param == "size":
                x = os.stat(new_dir[:-1]).st_size
                act.append(x)
            elif param == "access":
                x = os.stat(new_dir[:-1]).st_atime
                act.append(x)
            elif param == "modify":
                x = os.stat(new_dir[:-1]).st_mtime
                act.append(x)
            elif param == "creation":
                    x = os.stat(new_dir[:-1]).st_ctime
                    act.append(x)   
                        
        return act
        
    def list_of_files(self ,dir_name ,traversed = [], results = []): 
    
        dirs = os.listdir(dir_name)
        if dirs:
            for f in dirs:
                new_dir = dir_name + f + self.slash
                if os.path.isdir(new_dir) and new_dir not in traversed:
                    traversed.append(new_dir)
                    self.list_of_files(new_dir, traversed, results)
                else:
                    act = self.what_to_do(new_dir)
                    results.append(act)
        self.result_list = results  
        return results
        

        
def parse_args():
    desc = "Welcom To dirmap.py 1.0 \n Created DD 2013 RT"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc)
    parser.add_argument('-p','--path', help='Path To Original Directory', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-md','--md5', action = 'store_true',help='Show md5 hash of file', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-s','--size', action = 'store_true', help='Show size of file', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-a','--access', action = 'store_true',  help='Show access time of file', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-m','--modify', action = 'store_true', help='Show modification time of file', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-c','--creation', action = 'store_true', help='Show creation of file', required=False)
    
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    
    params = []
    for key,value in args.iteritems():
        if value == True:
            params.append(key)
    
    return args,params
    

    
def main():
    args , params = parse_args() 
    dir_path = args['path']
    map = Map(params)
    dir_list = map.list_of_files(dir_path)
    
    params.insert(0,"path")


    htmlcode_dir = HTML.table(dir_list,header_row=params)
    print htmlcode_dir
    
main()
```

I read a lot about this error but still couldn't manage to fix.
This is the traceback:

```
C:\Users\dd>C:\Users\dd\Desktop\dirmap.py -p C:\ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\dd\Desktop\dirmap.py", line 136, in <module>
    main()   File "C:\Users\dd\Desktop\dirmap.py", line 124, in main
    dir_list = map.list_of_files(dir_path)   File "C:\Users\dd\Desktop\dirmap.py", line 87, in list_of_files
    self.list_of_files(new_dir, traversed, results)   File "C:\Users\dd\Desktop\dirmap.py", line 81, in list_of_files
    dirs = os.listdir(dir_name) WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:/Documents and Settings\\*.*'
```

Any help?

Comment: You should read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/, start using `os.path.join()` or at least `os.path.sep`, and not use classes just because they are cool.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, could you explain more about using os.path.join() / os.path.sep , and your comment about the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all but I found that my problem was just permissions issue.
When reaching C:\ I needed to be administrator, and I wasn't.
Solved.